# Image gets new values even though mask is set to 0

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I'm working on a project where you user can insert a video and draw on it. But when trying to copy from a layer that contains the drawings to an image using mask, the image gets set to 0 even though mask value is 0.

```
     Mat copy = new Mat();
     img.CopyTo(copy);
     Mat[] array = transparent.Split();
     Mat transCopy = new Mat();
     CvInvoke.CvtColor(transparent, transCopy, ColorConversion.Rgba2Rgb);
     transCopy.CopyTo(copy, array[3]);
     Image.Image = copy.ToBitmap();
```

This is the function that I use to combine layer that has drawings (transparent) and my image (img).
The values of copy are good until second to last line of code where it gets set to 0.

Comment: did you imshow array[3] or array[3]>0 to make sure it is what you expect it to be?

Comment: I debugged it and it seemed alright. Its full of 0s so it wouldn't affect the image if i used it as mask.

Comment: most probably it is either a "bug" in your code, in the data or in the format and the function for masked copying itself is alright.